# Low CPU usage while running a spark job

Tags: java, apache-spark, cpu-usage

I am running a Spark job. I have 4 cores and worker memory set to 5G. Application master is on another machine in the same network, and does not host any workers. This is my code:

```
private void myClass() {
    // configuration of the spark context
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("myWork").setMaster("spark://myHostIp:7077").set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true");
    // creation of the spark context in which we will run the algorithm
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

    // algorithm
    for(int i = 0; i<200; i++) {
        System.out.println("===============================================================");
        System.out.println("iteration : " + i);
        System.out.println("===============================================================");
        ArrayList<Boolean> list = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
        for(int j = 0; j < 1900; j++){
            list.add(true);
        }
        JavaRDD<Ant> ratings = sc.parallelize(list, 100)
                    .map(bool -> new myObj())
                    .map(obj -> this.setupObj(obj))
                    .map(obj -> this.moveObj(obj))
                    .cache();
        int[] stuff = ratings
                    .map(obj -> obj.getStuff())
                    .reduce((obj1,obj2)->this.mergeStuff(obj1,obj2));
        this.setStuff(tour);

        ArrayList<TabObj> tabObj = ratings
                    .map(obj -> this.objToTabObjAsTab(obj))
                    .reduce((obj1,obj2)->this.mergeTabObj(obj1,obj2));
        ratings.unpersist(false);

        this.setTabObj(tabObj);
    }

    sc.close();
}
```

When I start it, I can see progress on the Spark UI, but it is really slow (I have to set the parallelize quite high, otherwise I have a timeout issue). I thought it was a CPU bottleneck, but the JVM CPU consumption is actually very low (most of the time it is 0%, sometime a bit more than 5%...).

The JVM is using around 3G Of memory according to the monitor, with only 19M cached.

The master host has 4 cores, and less memory (4G). That machine shows 100% CPU consumption (a full core) and I don't understand why it is that high... It just has to send partitions to the worker on the other machine, right?

Why is CPU consumption low on the worker, and high on the master?

Comment: Check number of partitions and number of tasks. Probably you have wrogn partition number after some step

Comment: What do you mean by a wrong number? Actually, it is a partition number issue because with a small dataset i don't have any probleme because i can set parralelism to 10 (it is ok for 4 cores) but with a bigger one i need more tasks (else, i got a timeout and if i set the timeout higher i got an other weird error...) and then it crashes  like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Make sure you have submit your Spark job by Yarn or mesos in the cluster, otherwise it may only running in your master node.
2. As your code are pretty simple it should be very fast to finish the computation, but i suggest to use wordcount example try to read few GB of input sources to test how the CPU consuming looks like.
3. Please use "local[*]" . * means use your All cores for computatation

   SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().set("spark.driver.host", "localhost").setAppName("unit-testing").setMaster("local[*]");
   References: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html
4. In spark there have a lot of things could influence the CPU and memory usage, such as executors and each spark.executor.memory you like to distribute.

Comment: I don't think i got a misconfiguration, because with a smaller dataset everything is fine, and my memory usage seems to be really lower than the max worker memory.

In local mode, it works, but i just want to use it on a cluster. My code is not really simple because in the setup and move function, there is a machine learning algorithme that iterate like 100000 times. If i'm not using parrallele computation it can last more than 45min. 

I'm using the standalone mode, and you are right, Spark developers advise consists in using yarn. That should be the reason of my issue...

Comment: Do you have single big dataset in your HDFS? or have multiple small files that could read by each nodes?

Comment: Also check your executors in the cluster, make sure each nodes have executor running on the machine.

Comment: My data set is really small, it's just some Mo. But i iterate a huge number of times in the data set (that is saved in memory at the beggining of the computation). I'm doing some Q-learning stuff so i have to create a high number of data to get my parameters converging into a clever solution. 

On the UI I can see an executor per machine, with 4 cores available and 5 Go available. When it stop running fast and the cpu usage fall to 0% on the slave machine, the memory usage is about 2.3Go on those slaves.(According to the slave's task manager)

Comment: Could you try to persistent data to RDD memory and try to use more complex algorithm for computing those data? check what is the CPU difference.

Comment: Also check your submit parameters https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

Comment: "Could you try to persistent data to RDD memory" I don't understand what you mean... My submit parameters are : 
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class launcher.Launcher
  --master spark://myIp:7077 \
  --executor-memory 5G \
  /home/myjar.jar
That looks ok for me but i maybe missing something.
I think it could be important to notice that there is a for loop. The first interations run well.

Comment: Check here https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence  In your logic code there could be persist the data to memory and also in your post code, there only have  for(int i = 0; i<200; i++) {    Because spark it running pretty fast you could try 2000,00 or more to see if could get much higher CPU utilization