# Very low CPU usage and slow execution on Spark in local mode

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to setup Spark in local mode ("local [*]").
I submitted test programs (query on jdbc connectors) and as I have already read that spark performance in local mode might not be the best as it's suppose to be run in cluster mode (and there it benefits the most (by-design)), I am still wondering why the CPU usage in the JVM process is so low - it oscillates between 0 and 5 and it looks like it is mostly because of setting up a spark or refreshing spark-ui processes?

[Low cpu usage while running a spark job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44972633/low-cpu-usage-while-running-a-spark-job)

I am surprised the accepted advice from the post above was to use yarn or mesos.
Isn't it that you only use them in cluster mode and in local (client) mode it doesn't really matter because driver and worker are in the same JVM?

Best regards,
matmakonen

Answer (score 0):

The cpu usage depends on your code or your logic.